# react-admin how to create client side list controller

Tags: react-admin

Do you know how to create client-side list controller?

I checked StackOverflow - I didn't find the answer to my question.

Is there a simple way to create a resource which reads all records from server on first page load.
And then the sort, filter, paging is done client side.
Also to have option to disable paging.

I tried to make a copy of `ListController.js` from ra-core and `List.js` from ra-ui-materialui and customize it, but error and I could go forward. I am new to react and making PoC.

Here is the error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined
>       (anonymous function)
>       node_modules/recompose/compose.js:22
>       19 |
>       20 | return funcs.reduce(function (a, b) {
>       21 | return function () {
>       22 | return a(b.apply(undefined, arguments));
>       23 | };
>       24 | });
>       25 | }
>       View compiled
>       ./src/ListController.js
>       src/ListController.js:431
>       428 | export default compose(
>       429 | connect(
>       430 | mapStateToProps,
>       431 | {
>       432 | crudGetList: crudGetListAction,
>       433 | changeListParams: changeListParamsAction,
>       434 | setSelectedIds: setListSelectedIdsAction,
>       View compiled

I have changed the imports from relative paths to import `react-admin`;
Any suggestions on how to fix the error?

This is the changed `ListController.js` file:

```
/* eslint no-console: ["error", { allow: ["warn", "error"] }] */
import { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { parse, stringify } from 'query-string';
import { push as pushAction } from 'react-router-redux';
import compose from 'recompose/compose';
import { createSelector } from 'reselect';
import inflection from 'inflection';
import debounce from 'lodash/debounce';
import isEqual from 'lodash/isEqual';
import pickBy from 'lodash/pickBy';

import removeEmpty from 'react-admin';
import queryReducer, {
    SET_SORT,
    SET_PAGE,
    SET_PER_PAGE,
    SET_FILTER,
    SORT_DESC,
} from 'react-admin';
import { crudGetList as crudGetListAction } from 'react-admin';
import {
    changeListParams as changeListParamsAction,
    setListSelectedIds as setListSelectedIdsAction,
    toggleListItem as toggleListItemAction,
} from 'react-admin';
import translate from 'react-admin';
import removeKey from 'react-admin';

/**
 * List page component
 *
 * The <List> component renders the list layout (title, buttons, filters, pagination),
 * and fetches the list of records from the REST API.
 * It then delegates the rendering of the list of records to its child component.
 * Usually, it's a <Datagrid>, responsible for displaying a table with one row for each post.
 *
 * In Redux terms, <List> is a connected component, and <Datagrid> is a dumb component.
 *
 * Props:
 *   - title
 *   - perPage
 *   - sort
 *   - filter (the permanent filter to apply to the query)
 *   - actions
 *   - filters (a React Element used to display the filter form)
 *   - pagination
 *
 * @example
 *     const PostFilter = (props) => (
 *         <Filter {...props}>
 *             <TextInput label="Search" source="q" alwaysOn />
 *             <TextInput label="Title" source="title" />
 *         </Filter>
 *     );
 *     export const PostList = (props) => (
 *         <List {...props}
 *             title="List of posts"
 *             sort={{ field: 'published_at' }}
 *             filter={{ is_published: true }}
 *             filters={<PostFilter />}
 *         >
 *             <Datagrid>
 *                 <TextField source="id" />
 *                 <TextField source="title" />
 *                 <EditButton />
 *             </Datagrid>
 *         </List>
 *     );
 */
export class ListController extends Component {
    state = {};

    componentDidMount() {
        if (
            !this.props.query.page &&
            !(this.props.ids || []).length &&
            this.props.params.page > 1 &&
            this.props.total > 0
        ) {
            this.setPage(this.props.params.page - 1);
            return;
        }

        this.updateData();
        if (Object.keys(this.props.query).length > 0) {
            this.props.changeListParams(this.props.resource, this.props.query);
        }
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        this.setFilters.cancel();
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        if (
            nextProps.resource !== this.props.resource ||
            nextProps.query.sort !== this.props.query.sort ||
            nextProps.query.order !== this.props.query.order ||
            nextProps.query.page !== this.props.query.page ||
            nextProps.query.filter !== this.props.query.filter
        ) {
            this.updateData(
                Object.keys(nextProps.query).length > 0
                    ? nextProps.query
                    : nextProps.params
            );
        }
        if (nextProps.version !== this.props.version) {
            this.updateData();
        }
    }

    shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
        if (
            nextProps.translate === this.props.translate &&
            nextProps.isLoading === this.props.isLoading &&
            nextProps.version === this.props.version &&
            nextState === this.state &&
            nextProps.data === this.props.data &&
            nextProps.selectedIds === this.props.selectedIds &&
            nextProps.total === this.props.total
        ) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Merge list params from 4 different sources:
     *   - the query string
     *   - the params stored in the state (from previous navigation)
     *   - the filter defaultValues
     *   - the props passed to the List component
     */
    getQuery() {
        const query =
            Object.keys(this.props.query).length > 0
                ? this.props.query
                : { ...this.props.params };
        const filterDefaultValues = this.props.filterDefaultValues || {};

        query.filter = { ...filterDefaultValues, ...query.filter };

        if (!query.sort) {
            query.sort = this.props.sort.field;
            query.order = this.props.sort.order;
        }
        if (!query.perPage) {
            query.perPage = this.props.perPage;
        }
        if (!query.page) {
            query.page = 1;
        }
        return query;
    }

    updateData(query) {
        const params = query || this.getQuery();
        const { sort, order, page = 1, perPage, filter } = params;
        const pagination = {
            page: parseInt(page, 10),
            perPage: parseInt(perPage, 10),
        };
        const permanentFilter = this.props.filter;
        this.props.crudGetList(
            this.props.resource,
            pagination,
            { field: sort, order },
            { ...filter, ...permanentFilter }
        );
    }

    setSort = sort => this.changeParams({ type: SET_SORT, payload: sort });

    setPage = page => this.changeParams({ type: SET_PAGE, payload: page });

    setPerPage = perPage =>
        this.changeParams({ type: SET_PER_PAGE, payload: perPage });

    setFilters = debounce(filters => {
        if (isEqual(filters, this.props.filterValues)) {
            return;
        }

        // fix for redux-form bug with onChange and enableReinitialize
        const filtersWithoutEmpty = removeEmpty(filters);
        this.changeParams({ type: SET_FILTER, payload: filtersWithoutEmpty });
    }, this.props.debounce);

    showFilter = (filterName, defaultValue) => {
        this.setState({ [filterName]: true });
        if (typeof defaultValue !== 'undefined') {
            this.setFilters({
                ...this.props.filterValues,
                [filterName]: defaultValue,
            });
        }
    };

    hideFilter = filterName => {
        this.setState({ [filterName]: false });
        const newFilters = removeKey(this.props.filterValues, filterName);
        this.setFilters(newFilters);
    };

    handleSelect = ids => {
        this.props.setSelectedIds(this.props.resource, ids);
    };

    handleUnselectItems = () => {
        this.props.setSelectedIds(this.props.resource, []);
    };

    handleToggleItem = id => {
        this.props.toggleItem(this.props.resource, id);
    };

    changeParams(action) {
        const newParams = queryReducer(this.getQuery(), action);
        this.props.push({
            ...this.props.location,
            search: `?${stringify({
                ...newParams,
                filter: JSON.stringify(newParams.filter),
            })}`,
        });
        this.props.changeListParams(this.props.resource, newParams);
    }

    render() {
        const {
            basePath,
            children,
            resource,
            hasCreate,
            data,
            ids,
            total,
            isLoading,
            translate,
            version,
            selectedIds,
        } = this.props;
        const query = this.getQuery();

        const queryFilterValues = query.filter || {};

        const resourceName = translate(`resources.${resource}.name`, {
            smart_count: 2,
            _: inflection.humanize(inflection.pluralize(resource)),
        });
        const defaultTitle = translate('ra.page.list', {
            name: `${resourceName}`,
        });

        return children({
            basePath,
            currentSort: {
                field: query.sort,
                order: query.order,
            },
            data,
            defaultTitle,
            displayedFilters: this.state,
            filterValues: queryFilterValues,
            hasCreate,
            hideFilter: this.hideFilter,
            ids,
            isLoading,
            onSelect: this.handleSelect,
            onToggleItem: this.handleToggleItem,
            onUnselectItems: this.handleUnselectItems,
            page: parseInt(query.page || 1, 10),
            perPage: parseInt(query.perPage, 10),
            refresh: this.refresh,
            resource,
            selectedIds,
            setFilters: this.setFilters,
            setPage: this.setPage,
            setPerPage: this.setPerPage,
            setSort: this.setSort,
            showFilter: this.showFilter,
            translate,
            total,
            version,
        });
    }
}

ListController.propTypes = {
    // the props you can change
    children: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    filter: PropTypes.object,
    filters: PropTypes.element,
    filterDefaultValues: PropTypes.object, // eslint-disable-line react/forbid-prop-types
    pagination: PropTypes.element,
    perPage: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    sort: PropTypes.shape({
        field: PropTypes.string,
        order: PropTypes.string,
    }),
    // the props managed by react-admin
    authProvider: PropTypes.func,
    basePath: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    changeListParams: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    crudGetList: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    data: PropTypes.object, // eslint-disable-line react/forbid-prop-types
    debounce: PropTypes.number,
    filterValues: PropTypes.object, // eslint-disable-line react/forbid-prop-types
    hasCreate: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
    hasEdit: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
    hasList: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
    hasShow: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
    ids: PropTypes.array,
    selectedIds: PropTypes.array,
    isLoading: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
    location: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    path: PropTypes.string,
    params: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    push: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    query: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    resource: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    setSelectedIds: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    toggleItem: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    total: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    translate: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    version: PropTypes.number,
};

ListController.defaultProps = {
    debounce: 500,
    filter: {},
    filterValues: {},
    perPage: 10,
    sort: {
        field: 'id',
        order: SORT_DESC,
    },
};

const injectedProps = [
    'basePath',
    'currentSort',
    'data',
    'defaultTitle',
    'displayedFilters',
    'filterValues',
    'hasCreate',
    'hideFilter',
    'ids',
    'isLoading',
    'onSelect',
    'onToggleItem',
    'onUnselectItems',
    'page',
    'perPage',
    'refresh',
    'resource',
    'selectedIds',
    'setFilters',
    'setPage',
    'setPerPage',
    'setSort',
    'showFilter',
    'total',
    'translate',
    'version',
];

/**
 * Select the props injected by the ListController
 * to be passed to the List children need
 * This is an implementation of pick()
 */
export const getListControllerProps = props =>
    injectedProps.reduce((acc, key) => ({ ...acc, [key]: props[key] }), {});

/**
 * Select the props not injected by the ListController
 * to be used inside the List children to sanitize props injected by List
 * This is an implementation of omit()
 */
export const sanitizeListRestProps = props =>
    Object.keys(props)
        .filter(props => !injectedProps.includes(props))
        .reduce((acc, key) => ({ ...acc, [key]: props[key] }), {});

const validQueryParams = ['page', 'perPage', 'sort', 'order', 'filter'];
const getLocationPath = props => props.location.pathname;
const getLocationSearch = props => props.location.search;
const selectQuery = createSelector(
    getLocationPath,
    getLocationSearch,
    (path, search) => {
        const query = pickBy(
            parse(search),
            (v, k) => validQueryParams.indexOf(k) !== -1
        );
        if (query.filter && typeof query.filter === 'string') {
            try {
                query.filter = JSON.parse(query.filter);
            } catch (err) {
                delete query.filter;
            }
        }
        return query;
    }
);

function mapStateToProps(state, props) {
    const resourceState = state.admin.resources[props.resource];

    return {
        query: selectQuery(props),
        params: resourceState.list.params,
        ids: resourceState.list.ids,
        selectedIds: resourceState.list.selectedIds,
        total: resourceState.list.total,
        data: resourceState.data,
        isLoading: state.admin.loading > 0,
        filterValues: resourceState.list.params.filter,
        version: state.admin.ui.viewVersion,
    };
}

export default compose(
    connect(
        mapStateToProps,
        {
            crudGetList: crudGetListAction,
            changeListParams: changeListParamsAction,
            setSelectedIds: setListSelectedIdsAction,
            toggleItem: toggleListItemAction,
            push: pushAction,
        }
    ),
    translate
)(ListController);
```

Answer (score 2):

It would be easier to handle this use case with a custom [`dataProvider`](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/DataProviders.html#writing-your-own-data-provider).

Each time you are executing an action in a List view (sorting, filtering, etc), React Admin asks the data from the data provider.

For example, say we want to list users, then filter them by gender, then sort them by age. The data provider will be called three times with the following arguments:

```
dataProvider('GET_LIST', 'user', { sort: defaultSort, filters: defaultFilters });
dataProvider('GET_LIST', 'user', { sort: defaultSort, filters: { gender: 'm' } });
dataProvider('GET_LIST', 'user', { sort: { field: 'age', order: 'DESC' }, filters: { gender: 'm' } });
```

So, in order to implement the behavior you want, your custom data provider would be something like:

```
// customDataResolver.js
import simpleRestProvider from 'ra-data-simple-rest';

const restDataProvider = simpleRestDataProvider('http://example.com/api');

let users; // In-memory cache (but you can write in storage or something)

export default (type, resource, params) => {
    if (type === 'GET_LIST' && resource === 'users') {
         if (!users) {
              return restDataProvider(type, resource, params)
                   .then((data) => {
                       users = data;
                       return data;
                   });
         }

         return users
             .sort(sortBy(params.sort))
             .filter(filterBy(params.filter));
    };

    return restDataProvider(type, resource, params);
};
```